# Как найти слово содержащее конкретные символы SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

**Задача такая:**

Напишите запрос, возвращающий фамилии всех сотрудников, в фамилии которых есть буквы **"a"** и
**"e"**

Максимум до чего я додумался:

```
SELECT last_name FROM  employees  where last_name LIKE "%a%e%";
```

Но я понимаю, что такой вариант возвращает все фамилии с нужными буквами, но где обязательно **'a'** стоит раньше чем **'e'** (Я сам задаю такой порядок в паттерне).Но этого не требуется.

Как все же получить нужный результат?

Comment: SELECT last_name FROM  employees  where last_name LIKE '%a%' AND last_name LIKE '%e%'; 
Такой вариант работает,но есть ли другой,более красивый способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быть может вам подойдет такой запрос:

```
SELECT last_name FROM employees where last_name LIKE "%a%" AND last_name LIKE "%e%";
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно найти регулярным выражением (более ли это красиво - это субъективно):

```
select last_name
from hr.employees
where regexp_like (last_name, 'a.*e|e.*a');

LAST_NAME
-------------------------
Baer
[...]
Fleaur
[...]
Sewall
Whalen

17 rows selected.
```